# How to test if a Linux directory contain only one subdirectory and no other files?

Tags: linux, sh

In a `/bin/sh` script, I'd like to check whether a directory contains only one subdir and no other files (aside from "." and "..", of course). I could probably parse the output of `ls`, but I also understand that's generally a bad idea. Suggestions?

Reason for questions: When I `zip` a folder on, say, a windows machine, and I unzip it under Linux, sometimes I get a directory whose contents are that of the original folder; sometimes I get a directory containing exactly one subdir, whose contents are that of the original folder. (I assume that there's something that varies in the way that I use `zip` under Windows, or that the various windows machines I use are configured slightly differently, or ...who knows?) Anhow, I'd like, on the Linux side, to handle both kinds of results in more or less the same way, hence this question.

For those thinking "What if your Windows-side folder really *did* contain just one subdir?", it happens that that's OK in this case, although I grant that it's a corner-case for the problem specification.

Comment: Why is parsing `ls` a bad idea?

Comment: See this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @ILikeTau: because `ls` can output whatever the hell it pleases depending on a lot of external factors out of control of your script. `ls` reacts to environment variables, locales configuration, config files, is inconsistent across Unixoid OSes, and should be considered a *user interface tool*, not a programming tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find` would be a good tool for this. It has some neat arguments:

- `-maxdepth 1` so it does not search recursively
- `-type d` searching only for directories
- `-printf 1` to overcome the problem with weird filenames (print `1` instead of the file name)

The full command is then:

```
find DIRECTORY -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf 1
```

This will print one character for each directory plus the directory itself so you are looking for directories that prints two characters (find has a nice feature that ignores `.` and `..` when searching).

Then, you want to check if there are no other (non-directory) files:

```
find DIRECTORY -maxdepth 1 ! -type d -printf 1
```

The full check will then be:

```
if [ "$(find DIRECTORY -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf 1 | wc -m)" -eq 2 \
        -a "$(find DIRECTORY -maxdepth 1 ! -type d -printf 1 | wc -m)" -eq 0 ]; then
    # It has only one subdirectory and no other content
fi
```

Or, you can make it one command using `-printf`'s `%y` which prints file type (`d` for directory):

```
if [ "$(find DIRECTORY -maxdepth 1 -printf %y)" = "dd" ]; then
    # It has only one subdirectory and no other content
fi
```

Comment: This is great..but it doesn't seem to work. I create a directory `foo` with one child dir `bar`, and run the script with `DIRECTORY` replaced by `foo` and (using `!#/bin/sh -fvx`) see that the eventual test is `[0 -eq 2]`.  Also: this seems to test whether there's exactly one subdir, but NOT to check that there are no context EXCEPT that subdir...is that right?

Comment: I found the problem: `wc -l` should be `wc -m`. I think I can make it also count non-dir files with a similar mechanism, and I'll be on my way. If you fix that typo, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @John Use `find . -type f` to search for files.  Try `man find`.

Comment: @John Yes, it should be `wc -m` (count of characters). I have also added check for other file types plus one-command check using find's `%y`

Comment: Gosh, that's a sweet final version. Thanks! You not only answered my question, I learned a lot, too!

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest issue in `/bin/sh` will be invisible files, since a `*` doesn't catch then [by default].

This will do what you want, I think:

```
#!/bin/bash
count_()
{
    echo $(( $# - 2 )) # -2 to remove . and ..
}
count()
{
    count_ * .*
}
ITEM_COUNT=$(count)
```

Of course you can adapt it to take a path as an argument if you wish.

Example output:

```
bash-3.2$ count
3
bash-3.2$ ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   5 christopher  wheel  170 Mar 18  2014 .
drwxrwxrwx   6 root         wheel  204 Jul  5 12:28 ..
drwxr-xr-x  14 christopher  wheel  476 Mar 18  2014 .git
drwxr-xr-x   5 christopher  wheel  170 Mar 18  2014 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 christopher  wheel  136 Mar 18  2014 pylib
```

Another example:

```
sh-3.2$ count_()
> {
>     echo $(( $# - 2 )) # -2 to remove . and ..
> }
sh-3.2$ count()
> {
>     count_ * .*
> }
sh-3.2$ ITEM_COUNT=$(count)
sh-3.2$ echo ${ITEM_COUNT}
3
```

**Sidenote:**

You're right that different zip implementations handle things differently, but on Linux, many tools treat `zip /path/to/folder` and `zip /path/to/folder/` differently *(which is absurdly irritating)*. If you're working in a controlled environment, you might want to instead normalize how things get zipped. However, if this is a user-facing thing, then that sucks.

**If you're not using `bash` as the invoking shell:**

`countFiles.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
count_()
{
    echo $(( $# - 2 )) # -2 to remove . and ..
}
count_ * .*
```

`scriptThatWantsTheCountOfFiles`:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
set count = `./countFiles.sh`
```

Comment: It is, as you guessed, a user-facing thing. Sigh. Is $(count) really the way to invoke the procedure "count"? This doesn't seem to be working for me (or maybe I'm expecting the wrong result). What should ITEM_COUNT be if (a) there's a subdir and a txt file? (b) a subdir only (c) a txt file only?

Comment: In `bash`, `$(...)` is the same as `\`...\``. If you're not using bash, then the scripts in my example should be in a different file altogether (I'll update my answer after this).

Comment: I'm using "/bin/sh" (I should have been more clear when I wrote "an sh script" that I meant "bin/sh" rather than just-any-old-shell).

Comment: Your last comment came through as gibberish... I see several things that look like 'count++', which seems odd.

Comment: I tried to paste in an execution (using `#!/bin/sh -fvx`) so that you could see how it wasn't working...but SO didn't seem to like formatting it like a nice grey box, so I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to parse output yourself, you can use `find`.

```
if [[ `find . -type d | wc -l` -eq 2 && \
      `find . -type f | wc -l` -eq 0 ]]; then

  echo yes

else

  echo no

fi
```

If you want to avoid recursing into the directory, you can specify `-maxdepth 1`.

See `man` [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for some of the other options.

Comment: I believe that doesn't work, for if the one subdirectory of `.` itself contains many other subdirectories, then the first count will be much larger than 2; you need, I believe, @stenSoft's idea of limiting the depth.

Comment: If you don't want to recurse into the directory, you do use `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: I believe it still doesn't work, for if the filename contains a newline (yep...that can happen!), `wc` will produce the wrong result. But thanks for doing the "dirs" and "files" tests and combining them; my `/bin/sh` skills are horribly rusty, and with your ideas and @stenSoft's, I'm pretty sure I can make this work.

Comment: If you need to handle newlines, you have to use something like `-print0`.  If you just need to count though, you can use something like `-printf x`.

Answer (score 0):

The number of links to the directory inode can help somewhat, but not solve completely the problem.  A directory has `2 + n` links pointing to it, being `n` the number of subdirectories created inside.  So, if you try to find all the directories with only `3` links, you'll get the directories with only one subdirectory inside.  But the only solution to get a *no files* directory is to search it.

Perhaps you can think in a mixed, two phase solution, in which first you find all the directories with `3` links pointing to them  (very efficient).  Then you read only those, finding for no plain files inside.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a portable shell function, tested in Dash:

```
check() {
    d=
    for i in "$1"/* "$1"/.* 
    do
        test ddd != "$d" && test -d "$i" || return 1
        d=d$d
    done
    test ddd = "$d"
}
```

We use the variable `d` to count how many directories we've seen.  We're expecting three (`.`, `..` and the target directory).  If we've already seen three, then exit early; similarly if we've seen a non-directory.

If we make it to the end of the loop, we check that we've seen three directories; the return value of `test` becomes the return value of the function.